# Implementación del SearchView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy tratando de usar un filtro, pero al momento de ejecutar la app se cierra[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes agregar la traza del error

Comment: no me sale la error en el codigo, pero añadi la imagen del mensaje que me sale en consola

Comment: Muy bien, pero trata mejor de copiar y pegar el codigo aqui, en lugar de las imagenes, algunos usuarios del sitio no pueden verlas y no podran ayudar, ademas de que es mas facil porder probar en algun momento el codigo y asi poderte dar una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error de casteo, en tu menu.xml debes tener algo como esto :

```
 <item
   android:id="@+id/action_search"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
   android:title="@string/action_search"
   android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
   android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Y en tu Activity estas importando algo como esto:

```
 import android.widget.SearchView;
```

En el XML y en el activity debes invocar al mismo elemento